# Error when I use two dbml files with same table names in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have to copy data from database tables to another database with the same table names. For this reason, I added two dbml files (to map database tables) to projects. But LINQ issues this error :

> "Severity Code Description Project File   Line Suppression State
>   Error CS0579  Duplicate
>   'global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute' attribute"

Comment: And what code did you use to produce this error? On what line of code did you get this error?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse var db = new dbContext();

Comment: So you haven't created a class derived from DbContext representing your source and destination databases?